# delete and update operations from a single query

Tags: mysql

I have two tables USERS and STUDENTS. I want to delete a record from STUDENT table and Update one column in USERS table for that particular student. I want to do that with a single (MYSQL) query, please help me out.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do that with single query. You can consider wrapping all these queries in transaction instead.

Comment: I am working on PHP Codeigniter (MVC) framework, how can i use transaction here?